# Why do I have to use a bookmark to logout of SuperUser?

Tags: discussion, firefox, logout

I entered SuperUser via a standard Login.  Then I couldn't Logout.  There was no button or link to do that.  I looked under the StachExchange sign at the upper-left, and all it produced was a message about visiting the Stack Exchange Network.  I finally found a hidden link on the page by looking at the page-source (Firefox Cmd-U). It was this: 'https://superuser.com/users/logout' which seems like something that should be visible to the client.

Comment: Did you click on the little "hamburger-like" image in the right of the black bar on the top?

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

[image]